# How to allow clients to manage their website?

Tags: html, css, web, administration

I do small websites for local companies. All I know is HTML5 and CSS3, no JavaScript, no PHP.

I have this client who wants me to make a website for his coffee shop. All good so far. I have an idea for a beautiful responsive design which will get his coffee shop a lot of fame.

**The problem:**
The guy wants to be able to manage his website, meaning: he wants to add a photo if he needs to, or even some text on a particular page. He doesn't want to depend on me so he wants to do it by himself. The problem is that I can't teach him HTML so he would download the HTML file and write the code for the desired thing.. I need to do beautiful websites for my portfolio.

**No Wordpress**: I don't like Wordpress because it's limited so I can't be creative with the design. I thought of that as being the only solution requiring his needs.

**I'm willing to learn more**: if there is a solution that I could implement in one month or two, I will do this and learn what is needed, but can't learn PHP in two months.

Any advice?

Comment: Wordpress, once you've mastered it, is extremely flexible. But it does require PHP knowledge, in my view. Perhaps you could do some searching for "PHP CMS" - there are _loads_ out there. There's no substitute for downloading a few and setting them up - perhaps you'll find one you like that way?

Answer (score 0):

You might find that [CushyCMS](https://www.cushycms.com/en) does what you want. From the site:

- Allow clients to safely edit content
- No software to install, no programming required
- Takes just a few minutes to setup
- Define exactly which parts of the page can be changed
- Produces standards compliant, search engine friendly content

From experience, a couple of downsides:

- No choice of editor
- You have to add pages that can be edited - the client cannot create new pages.

Comment: is it safe to share the ftp login with cushyCMS?

Comment: Sorry for the delay to this response. There are always risks with sharing any login, however Cushy is pretty trustworthy. I've had numerous customers who use it with nary a problem.